# how to add current date as start date while generating a mpp file using java?

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

I am working on a small project where we need to generate a MPP plan from reference plan. In my reference mpp file i have some old date. When we are generating the new plan we are expecting the start date of the project should be current date. I tried by exploring the available methos of Calander( MPXJ project file calander). My requirement is to set the Task's start date as curent date. But there are no methods available to set the tesks startdate.  Will be helpful if i get quick response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
String today = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime())+"";
/* 
 *    if you want it in date format then
 *    java.util.Date today = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently MPXJ doesn't support writing to an MPP File. You may consider using [Aspose Tasks](https://products.aspose.com/tasks) to write something to an MPP file.

- Remember, it's not free.